# Where to place 'this.setState in this case?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, state, setstate

I'm trying to make a page where you can click on a thumbnail, and get an enlarged version to display, using state. Got the state working just fine, but I get the error message `Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined` when trying to set it in an `onClick` on the thumbnails. I can understand why it doesn't really work like this, but having a hard time understanding exactly how to arrange things for it to work the way I intend it to. Here's the code in question:

```
const WorkThumb = ({work}) => (
  <Col xs={3} md={4}>
    <WorkImage src={work.metadata.image.imgix_url} onClick={this.setState({selected: work._id})} />
  </Col>
)

export default class ArtContent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {selected: props.works[0]["_id"]};
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Row>
        <Col xs={6}>
          <Row between="xs" center="xs" middle="xs">
            {this.props.works.map((work) => (
              <WorkThumb key={work._id} work={work} />
            ))}
          </Row>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={6}>
          <Selected src={this.props.works.filter((work) => (work["_id"] == this.state.selected))[0].metadata.image.imgix_url} />
        </Col>
      </Row>
    )
  }
}
```

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `setState` on **stateless** component that should be a pure function (i.e. depends only on its arguments: no `this` context, no state, same input - same output). But you can pass a callback from its stateful parent

```
const WorkThumb = ({work, onSelect}) => (
  <Col xs={3} md={4}>
    <WorkImage src={work.metadata.image.imgix_url} onClick={() => onSelect(work)} />
  </Col>
)

export default class ArtContent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {selected: props.works[0]["_id"]};
    this.selectWork = this.selectWork.bind(this)
  }

  selectWork(work) {
    this.setState(...)
  } 

  render () {
    return (
      <Row>
        <Col xs={6}>
          <Row between="xs" center="xs" middle="xs">
            {this.props.works.map((work) => (
              <WorkThumb key={work._id} work={work} onSelect={this.selectWork} />
            ))}
          </Row>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={6}>
          <Selected src={this.props.works.filter((work) => (work["_id"] == this.state.selected))[0].metadata.image.imgix_url} />
        </Col>
      </Row>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!